# How many concurrent requests a single instance (POD) can handle?

Tags: docker, kubernetes-pod, autoscaling

It's a silly question, but still.

While doing back-of-the-envelope calculations, I realised that I don't have any understanding regarding how many instances (PODs) of my service should I have in cluster to cope with the given load requirements.

Could you please share any useful resource on that matter?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There is no certain limitation for request count. You can handle as much request as your infrastructure can handle. It can be changeable based on the infrastructure.

`- CPU consumption per request`

`- Memory consumption per request`

`- Network consumption per request`

`- CPU / Memory requests & limits for pods`

`- Network capabilities of the infrastructure`

are the basic consideration which should be tested and monitored before deciding the pod count of the application.